# Formula error message when adding new rows to tables in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

*I always use tables when working with Excel, but recently I’ve run into a strange new issue. I'm assuming it's just a bug and I'll need to reinstall but this issue is on my work system and that will take no end of red tape.*

**The issue**
When I add a new row to any table (whether by pressing tab in the last table cell or entering data beneath the table) I get an error message saying Excel detected issues with my formulas.

[image: The error message]

**What I've done**

- I checked my formulas
- I checked my other workbooks
- I ran the Inquire plugin to look for hidden formula
- I recreated the sheet in a new book
- I made a whole new table, with no formulas anywhere, in a new book

**What I found**
So now I get this error message in all books, even when my formulas are fine or there *are* no formulas in the book. I haven't changed anything recently that would have done this so I'm at a loss.

As I said, I'm thinking a reinstall may fix it, but that would be a major change (I don’t have the required permissions) and this isn't having an adverse effect on my books; it's just really, really annoying.

**The question**
Has anyone else had this happen to them? Does anyone have any idea of how to fix this without a reinstall?

*Excel 2013 Professional Plus running on Windows 7 Enterprise*

Comment: Does it happen in excel safe mode? Maybe an add-in is doing something? What if you look in the `Name Manager` for anything that's an invalid reference?

Comment: Thanks @Raystafarian; I ran it in safe and it worked fine I removed a `Visual Studio Tools for Office 2003` add-in that I've never heard of before and the error has gone now. Could you frame this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try opening excel in safe mode (hold <kbd>CTRL</kbd> while opening the program).

If that works, you'll need to check to see if any add-ons or your personal macro workbook are the problem by systematically disabling each of them and then checking.

Comment: Removing a few Add-ins that were designed for older versions of Excel fixed the problem. Thanks.